# Why is Camera deprecated API?

Tags: android, api, camera, android-5.0-lollipop

I am developing a Camera App for android. I am new to Android.
In eclipse, every single line is marked as deprecated in Android 5.0

What is wrong with old Camera API ? 
I cant seem to find any tutorial or new organization of the new Camera API anywhere.
Where can I learn more about new Camera?

Comment: To see how to use the updated Camera API, refer to the Camera2Basic and Camera2Video implementation samples in this release.

Comment: You can find updated information here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html

and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.html

Comment: What is wrong with you people? You are marking this as a duplicate of a later question? @NinjaCat